# Django: Template search order for the authentication system (to create my own auth templates)

Tags: django, templates, authentication

I am using the default authentication system of Django (v1.8.12), but I want to create my own templates (actually according to the documentation `django.contrib.auth` do not provide any template).

Then I added the folder 'registration' inside the 'templates' folder of my application 'mainApp'. According to the documentation this is the right place, a folder named 'registration'.

I have also created the template 'login.html', and this template is loaded properly at the defined url '...account/login'.

The problem is with the other templates:

- logged_out.html
- password_change_done.html
- password_change_form.html
- password_reset_complete.html
- password_reset_confirm.html
- password_reset_done.html
- password_reset_email.html
- password_reset_form.html

The previous templates are been loaded from the 'admin' application and not from my app.

How can I tell Django that my 'registration' templates should be loaded and not the templates defined in the admin application?

My project url.py is

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('mainApp.urls', namespace="mainApp")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^account/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

My template settings are the default settings

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': True,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: OK. I just tried this in the template settings and is now working `'DIRS': ['mainApp/templates'],`. Anyway I am open to a more generic solution that you can give me :).

Comment: Update the previous solution does not work in production (I mean in the server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move `mainApp` above `django.contrib.admin` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting, so that Django searches the `mainApp/templates` directory first.

That way, you don't need to add `mainApp/templates` to your `DIRS` setting.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

Is there any bad implication of adding my app to the top of `INSTALLED_APPS`?

I think the documentation recommends to add our own apps at the end of the default list.

Comment: It should be ok most of the time, as long as you are aware that your app's templates, static files etc will be chosen first. Occasionally there might be a dependency issue, for example if you call `admin.site.unregister(User)` and register your own model admin for `User`. In that case, your app would need to go below `django.contrib.auth`.